# How to use pip with python3.5 after upgrade from 3.4?

Tags: python, pip, version, python-3.5

I'm on Ubuntu and I have python2.7, (it came pre-installed) python3.4, (used before today) and python3.5, which I upgraded to today, installed in parallel. They all work fine on their own.

However, I want to use `pip` to install some packages, and I can't figure out how to do this for my 3.5 installation because `pip` installs for 2.7 and `pip3` installs python 3.4 packages.

For instance, I have asyncio installed on 3.4, but I can't import it from 3.5. When I do `pip3 install aysncio`, it tells me the requirement is already satisfied.

I'm a bit of a newbie, but I did some snooping around install directories and couldn't find anything and I've googled to no avail.

Comment: Does it really affect you that `pip3` references python3.4 rather than python3.5?

Comment: @zondo Yes, because then I can't use it to install packages on 3.5. I've tried to use pip3 to install packages, and it installs the 3.4 version. Maybe reference isn't the right word. I can't find the pip for python3.5.

Comment: I suppose my question should have been, "Is the 3.5 version different from the 3.4 version?"

Comment: @zondo Yes. For instance, I have asyncio installed on 3.4, but I can't import it from 3.5. When I do `pip3 install aysncio`, it tells me the requirement is already satisfied.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suppose you can run `pip` through Python until this is sorted out. (https://docs.python.org/dev/installing/)

A quick googling seems to indicate that this is indeed a bug. Try this and report back:

```
python3.4 -m pip --version
python3.5 -m pip --version
```

If they report different versions then I guess you're good to go. Just run `python3.5 -m pip install package` instead of `pip3 install package` to install 3.5 packages.

Comment: They both show 1.5.4 but with the corresponding python version at the end in parentheses. Installing through the language works great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to setup a virtual environment:

```
$ python3.4 -m venv envdir
$ source envdir/bin/activate
$ pip --version
```

Obviously, this won't install the packages globally and you'll have to `source venv/bin/activate` every time you wan to make use of it.

Comment: Which isn't a bad thing at all, considering that it will keep the system packaged stuff and the ones from PyPI cleanly separated.